# An unhandled exception of type System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception occurred in FlaUI.Core.dll

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, flaui

I am trying some windows application automation using flaUi automation.
here I tried to click on menu in an application which supposed to load form before perform any further action.

Code:

```
 var menu = mainwindow.Automation.GetDesktop().FindFirstDescendant(cf.Menu()).AsMenuItem();
 menu.Items["Report"].Items["CR Reports"].Items["Bk Report"].Invoke();
```

It throws error on second line of code.

This works fine on one system and same code throwing an:

> unhandled exception of type system.componentmodel.Win32Exception occurred in flaui.core.dll exception

on another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Catch that Win32Exception, and post exception details for more info. Sample code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=net-5.0

Comment: Looks like you are trying to find the menuitem on the Desktop, instead of the application itself. Shouldn't it instead be `mainwindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf=>cf.Menu()).AsMenu();` Also notice I am using `AsMenu`, instead of `AsMenuItem`.

Comment: Hi Marshal, Thank you so much for you prompt reply. I will share the exception details, as for second suggestion, This is working absolutely fine on one system but same line of code throwing error on another, Not able to identify the cause. Please help!